# Javascript right way of OOP

Tags: javascript, oop

I am little confused 
I figured out that there are many ways in javascript how to do OOP
Can u tell me what is the difference and which one is the right one ?

```
class Dog{
 bark(){}
}

var Dog = {
  bark : function(){}
}

var Dog = function(){
  this.bark = function(){}
}
```

Comment: `which one is the right one` Right for what purpose? This question is way too broad - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think this is like asking which version of GNU CCC Is the best. Of course, the lastest stable version. So `class Dog` it is

Comment: The first one (`class Dog`) is ES6. So if you run your code in an environment which supports ES6, then by all means you should use it. If however you want to run your code directly in browsers (or other environments, such as old Node.js installs) which do no support it, then of course you'll have to use one of the other variants (there are actually plenty more).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The fist one is introduced in ES6. This helps programmer from other programming language like Java to write the Javascript easily.
2. The second creation of object using javascript object literal.
3. The last one is the function known as Constructor. You can use the constructor to create javascript object like this

   var object = new Dog();

There exists another way to create javascript object using the Object constructor as follows

```
var object = new Object();
```

All above methods are right way of creating object literal. Here are some benefits of using object literal

1. Its shorter to type
2. It emphasizes that objects are simply mutable hashes and not something that needs to be baked from a “recipe” (from a class)

Comment: `Object.create`

Answer (score 1):

If you **know you have ES6 features** available, I would go with the first option:

```
class Dog {
  bark() {
    // code here
  }
}
```

The other ways you mentioned have flaws.

- The second way creates an object instance, not a class.
- The third way is acceptable, but it is better to attach the method to the prototype, in most cases.

If you are **not certain you have ES6 features available**, than do this:

```
function Dog() {
  // init
}

Dog.prototype.bark = function() {
  // code here
};
```

EDIT:
As others pointed out, you question is somewhat situational and/or opinion-based. That is, different situations may call for different approaches, and different developers will give different answers based on their personal taste. However, the answers I gave above are what the general JS community has agreed upon, so I recommend you use them for most situations.

Answer (score -2):

The is class in js but still be introduced for browors wont work ,the second is  make object somethnig like an array, the last one is oop in a way ...if you what oop use typescript it is javascript oop to me

```
var Dog = function(){ this.bark = function(){} }
```

Comment: Check out [ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: Yeah but thats lib i mean js basic

Comment: That's not a library, it's the next version of JavaScript, already implemented in a [few browsers](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).